# Proxy calls are all reverting in test suite despite implementation being set and initialised

Tags: tokens, testing, openzeppelin, proxy-contracts

I am currently writing an upgradable contract using the unstructured data proxy model and an ERC20 token implementation (similar to USDC).

This means the traditional approach of sending a transaction to a proxy and it hitting the fallback function (unless you are the admin) and delegating the call to the implementation while storing the state in the proxy.

Currently, I am writing a test suite that deploys both contracts and sets the implementation's initialise function via the proxy.

I am running into an error that no matter what call I give the proxy, whether it be asking for the symbol via "symbol()" or asking for the minter role, it always reverts (but shouldn't):

> Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert

If I use the admin key, it correctly fails with:

> Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert Cannot call fallback function from the proxy admin

However, it should not revert when calling functions defined in the implementation. My code for this test is as follows:

```
const { accounts, contract, web3 } = require('@openzeppelin/test-environment');
const [ admin, user, recipient ] = accounts;
// Loads the built artifact from build/contracts/ERC20.json
const ERC20 = contract.fromArtifact('ERC20');
const Proxy = contract.fromArtifact('Proxy');
// test framework
const { expect } = require('chai');
//erc20 generic tests
const shouldBehaveLikeErc20 = require("./behaviors/ERC20.behavior.js");
const shouldBehaveLikeErc20Detailed = require("./behaviors/ERC20Detailed.behavior.js");

describe('ERC20', function () {

    const name = 'ERC20';
    const symbol = 'ERC20';
    const decimals = 18;
    const totalSupply = web3.utils.toBN("1e28");

    beforeEach(async function() {
        this.ERC20 = await ERC20.new();
        this.ERC20V2 = await ERC20.new();
        let data = web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionSignature('initialize()');
        this.Proxy = await Proxy.new(this.ERC20.address, admin, data, { from: admin });
    });

    it("should behave like ERC20", function() {
        //need ERC20 ABI with Proxy address as Proxy delegates
        this.token = this.ERC20;
        this.token.address = this.Proxy.address;
        shouldBehaveLikeErc20(accounts, totalSupply);
        shouldBehaveLikeErc20Detailed(name, symbol, decimals)
    });

    it('the deployer is the minter', async function () {
        let abi = {
                "constant": true,
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "internalType": "address",
                        "name": "account",
                        "type": "address"
                    }
                ],
                "name": "isMinter",
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "internalType": "bool",
                        "name": "",
                        "type": "bool"
                    }
                ],
                "payable": false,
                "stateMutability": "view",
                "type": "function"
            };
        let functionData = web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionCall(abi, [ admin ]);
        //always reverts here, but it shouldn't 
        let result = await web3.eth.call({
            from: user,
            to: this.Proxy.address,
            functionData
        });
        expect(web3.eth.abi.decodeParameter('bool', result)).to.equal(true);
    });

    it('upgrades the implementation address', async function () {
        await this.Proxy.upgradeTo(this.ERC20V2.address, { from: admin });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly me, I forgot to include the data object key...

```
let result = await web3.eth.call({
            from: user,
            to: this.MyContract.address,
            data: functionData //forgot data:
        });
```